# Fail to add legend to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I tried to add legend to my ggplot, but I failed.
The code can be run, but the legend did not show up in my R plot Window. I tried scale_linetype_identity()and theme(legend.position="right"), and it didn't work.

This is the function I used in plotting:

```
r.AB = function(x) {
return(0.5*(exp(4*x)-1)/(exp(4*x)+1))}

r.AB.2 = function(x) {
return(0.5*(1-exp(-2*x))) }

r.AB.3 = function(x) {
return(x)
}
```

This is how I do ggplot:

```
distance<-data.frame(x=c(0, 2), y= c(0,0.5))
base <- ggplot(distance, aes(x,y)) + ylim(0, 0.5) + xlim(0, 2)
base + geom_function(stat = "function", fun = r.AB.3, mapping = aes(x,y), lty = 1, col     
="black")+
geom_path(aes(x,y), stat = "function", fun = r.AB.2, lty = 2, col ="black")+
geom_path(aes(x,y),stat = "function", fun = r.AB, lty = 3, col ="black")+
ggtitle("Mapping Function")+
scale_x_continuous("Genectic distance (M)")+scale_y_continuous("recombination fraction")+
theme(legend.position="right")
```

Comment: You need to move `linetype` inside `aes()` to get legends. I show an example of "manual legends" (with colors, not line types) here, if interested: https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/manual-legends-ggplot2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be:

```
r.AB = function(x) {
        return(0.5*(exp(4*x)-1)/(exp(4*x)+1))}

r.AB.2 = function(x) {
        return(0.5*(1-exp(-2*x))) }

r.AB.3 = function(x) {
        return(x)
}

distance<-data.frame(x=c(0, 2), y= c(0,0.5))
base <- ggplot(distance, aes(x,y)) + ylim(0, 0.5) + xlim(0, 2)
base + geom_function(stat = "function", fun = r.AB.3, mapping = aes(x,y, lty = "solid"), col ="black")+
        geom_path(aes(x,y, lty = "dashed"),  stat = "function", fun = r.AB.2,  col ="black")+
        geom_path(aes(x,y, lty = "smaller_dashed"),stat = "function", fun = r.AB,  col ="black")+
        ggtitle("Mapping Function")+
        scale_x_continuous("Genectic distance (M)")+scale_y_continuous("recombination fraction")+
        theme(legend.position="right") +
        scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid" = 1, "dashed" = 2, "smaller_dashed" = 3))
```

[image]